# Difference between lex compiler and C compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, lex

which code can be compiled by using lex compiler. What is the difference between these two compilers?

Answer (score 1):

A lex file is a file that contains regular expressions and embedded C code. The lex tool takes a lex file and translates it into a pure C file that only contains the C code from the lex file along with code generated from the regular expressions.

The C compiler is a tool that takes a C file and translates it into machine code.

So if you're using lex, your workflow is: write a lex file, use lex to create a C file, use the C compiler to compile that C file (along with the other C files in your project).

If you're not using lex the workflow is: write a C file, use the C compiler to compile it.

The reason that you'd use lex is that writing regular expression to generate a lexer is often easier than writing the equivalent C code yourself.